# Redirecting in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, redirect

I have an issue redirecting to another page in codeigniter, this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var url = $('#baseurl').val();
        var form = $('#customerinfo');

        $('#next').click(function (e) {

            if ($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {
                // Prevent submit.
                e.preventDefault();
                //Start loading
                var checkbox = $('#Accept');
                if (checkbox[0].checked == true)
                {
                    $.post(url + 'customerinfo/next', form.serialize(), function(response) {window.location.href=url + 'paymentinfo';});
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $("#errmsg .msg").text("You need to read and accept the terms and conditions before you can continue!");
                    $("#errmsg").css("display", "block");
                }

                $(".loading-add-ticket").css("display", "block"); 
                // Send request.

            }   
            else console.log ( "invalid form" );


        });


    });
</script>
```

**What it does:**
When the next button is clicked it submits the form via ajax, the form is then processed on the server and upon completion the user is redirected using the following block of code:

```
    <?php
    class CustomerInfo extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
        {
            // Write to $title
            $this->template->write('title', 'Customer Info');

            // Write to $content
            $this->template->write_view('content', 'tickets/customerinfo');

            // Write to $sidebar
            $this->template->write_view('sidebar', 'sidebar');

            // Render the template
            $this->template->render();
        }

        function next()
        {
            if ($_POST) {

                if (isset($_POST['Accept']))
                {
                    $data[0] = array(
                        'TravelInsurance' => $_POST['TravelInsurance'],
                        'LuggagePayment' => $_POST['LuggagePayment'],
                        'Donations' => $_POST['Donations'],
                        'FirstName' => $_POST['FirstName'],
                        'LastName' => $_POST['LastName'],
                        'CityTown' => $_POST['CityTown'],
                        'ContactNo' => $_POST['ContactNo'],
                        'Address' => $_POST['Address'],
                        'Accept' => $_POST['Accept']

                    );

                    $this->session->set_userdata('customerinfo', $data);
                    redirect(site_url('paymentinfo'));  
                }


            }

        }

    }
?>
```

The problem:
The redirect never happens, when i check the post response using firebug in my browser i notice that the target page has been returned :

[image]

**What i want:** I need the page to be redirected to the target page, i am new to codeigniter so i do not know what i am doing wrong.

**current fix:**
In the success function on my ajax function i am using javascript to redirect to the next page but i do not want the redirects to be handled on the client side.

Comment: Then do a direct submit and do not use `$.post` (remember that ajax is async) ...cheers

Comment: is the block of code starting with function next() in your controller? can you post the form?

Comment: Yes it is. I have added the full controller code.

Comment: Can you post your html form?

Comment: Nevermind, Robert's answer worked for me. Thanks o7

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes with forms i prefer to use

```
header("Location: /Controller/method/value");
```

i know that's a dirty method but sometimes is helpful